# GPG key not working for signing commits in Github

Tags: git, github, gnupg

I got this to work one time, but now it won't work anymore. It said the commits were "verified" with a GPG key I used and then later they said "unverified". I created a new key and followed the same process that I used to create the key I used before and no luck. I wanted to do this so it would say my commits were "verified", but I guess it's not needed. It just looks good.

I was running this command `git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' -- --all` in a couple of my repos to make all my commits verified and it worked until I refreshed the commit list later and they said "unverified". It says "This user has not yet uploaded their public signing key." even though it is right in my key list in Github.

I have everything setup correctly as far as I know (yes my email is the same in Github):
[image]

[image]

[image]